# AMPscript multiple if/elseif statement throwing error "IF Not Closed"

Tags: ampscript

I have the below code but it's throwing off error saying If statement is not closed with EndIf. I tried a few variations with different use of () but no luck. Would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
%%[

SET @CurrentCourse = Item_Group__c
SET @Location = Location__c

IF IndexOf(@Location, "Melbourne") > 0 AND @CurrentCourse == "Course 1" THEN 
SET @NextCourse = "Course A" 
SET @CurrentPermit = "Permit 1"

ELSEIF IndexOf(@Location, "Sydney" > 0 AND @CurrentCourse == "Course 1" THEN 
SET @NextCourse = "Course B" 
SET @CurrentPermit = "Permit 1"

ELSEIF IndexOf(@Location, "Perth") > 0 AND @CurrentCourse == "Course 1" THEN 
SET @NextCourse = "Course C" 
SET @CurrentPermit = "Permit 2"

ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have worked it out by setting variables for IndexOf before stating If statements. So...

```
%%[

SET @Melbourne = IndexOf(@Location, "Melbourne")
SET @Sydney = IndexOf(@Location, "Sydney")
SET @Perth = IndexOf(@Location, "Perth")

IF @Melbourne > 0 AND @CurrentCourse == "Course 1" THEN 
SET @NextCourse = "Course A" 
SET @CurrentPermit = "Permit 1"

ELSEIF @Sydney > 0 AND @CurrentCourse == "Course 1" THEN 
SET @NextCourse = "Course B" 
SET @CurrentPermit = "Permit 1"

ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were missing a parenthesis on your first else if after “Sydney”

ELSEIF IndexOf(@Location, "Sydney" >